# Is it possible for me to have an e-mail account in a Stack Exchange domain?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, email

Hello,

Is it possible to get an email account in my-site.stackexchange.com domain? If so, how can I get it?

Cheers, 
Tomek

Comment: Given that the whole issue about Stack Exchange domain names is kind of up in the air at this point... not yet, at least. Still a good question to see if this is a possibility some time in the future, and under what conditions it could happen.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a fairly straightforward 5 step process:

1. Set up a mail server, or get a mail account at google or some other provider.  Email to your new email address "awesomesauce@gamedev.stackexchange.com" will end up there.
2. Get buddy-buddy with one of the people at stack overflow internet services - it can be anyone.
3. Become such a good friend to that person that they would walk on fire for you, swallow swords, and even run exe files you send them.
4. Create a trojan horse that will infect the firewall server at stack overflow internet services when run from your buddy's work computer.
5. Configure the trojan remotely to monitor the TCP/IP traffic going through, and redirect any email with the to: going to your desired address to the email account or mail server you set up in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment: **No**

I know there has been a discussion about moderators possibly getting email address linked to the domains they moderate, but this has never been high priority.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it'd actually be useful. Users generally use mod flags to talk to mods and team@stackoverflow.com to talk to the dev team; there's no need for an e-mail address for mods. The only use I can see is having e-mails from mods to users show up as coming from that address instead of the mod's personal address

Comment: @Michael That was the objective of the discussion to allow mods to send mail from an "official" address. I am particularly not bothered but thought it relevant to mention in case it does happen in future.

Answer (score 2):

Would community members be willing to pay for a gmail-like email account on SE? I would. Might be something to monetize the system. idk, probably wouldn't pay enough to cover the cost of salaries+equipment...

Would that be something that the SE team would relish taking on?